# Properties of Partial Derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Do Partial Derivatives have the property, for some general set of variables x,y,z,
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$$
like exact derivatives do, i.e., $$\frac{d x}{d y}\frac{d y}{d z}=\frac{d x}{d z}$$

Comment: This is just the chain rule. It is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Partial differentials don't have properties like you are wanting, because partial differentials aren't, generally speaking, unique.

The $\partial y$ in $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is a *different* variable than the $\partial y$ in $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$.  This is why the partials are never split up - part of their identity is based on the lower part of the fraction.

There are some notational options you can use to keep track of which quantity is which, and then you can treat them algebraically as above.  One option is to mark which variable is allowed to freely vary.

For instance, if I had $z = y^2 + x^3$, then I could mark the partial of $z$ when $y$ was allowed to vary freely as $\partial_y z$.  So, $\partial_y z = 2y\,dy$.  Or, $\frac{\partial_y z}{dy} = 2y$.

If you keep track of which is which in a fashion like this, then normal algebraic rules apply.